# Variable does not exist: con

Tags: apex

whats wrong with this code?
I am trying to loop through a list of contacts and for some reason it doesnt like the var con. I know its something very simple that i am missing, which makes me feel i shouldnt be working on a sunday

This is the SOQL i am using on the batch process to fetch the records

> SELECT Id, name, (SELECT Id,accountid, Name,email FROM Contacts order
>   by createddate asc) FROM Account

```
map<Id,List<contact>> mapContacts = new map<Id,List<contact>>();
for(sObject s : objectBatch)
        {
            Account a = (Account)s;
            mapContacts.put(a.id,a.contacts);
        }

for(Id accid : mapContacts.keyset())
        {
            List<contact>  contactList = new List<contact>();
            contactList = mapContacts.get(accid);
            system.debug(contactList);
            for(Contact con : contactList);
            {
                String key ='';
                contacts.clear();
                system.debug(con); //  Variable does not exist: con

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the semi-colon in the for loop statement; you have made the loop empty with a following block not related to it.

```
for (Contact con : contactList) {
    String key ='';
    contacts.clear();
    System.debug(con);
}
```

Comment: Phew!! Time to stop everything and have a cup of coffee.